# Titanium: platform detection and changing interface style accordingly

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

As you may be aware different platform will require slightly different UX/UI.

Example, when you design for the iphone, you might have a back button, however when you build for android, you do not want a back button.

Other things is icons, you might have multiple buttons on the toolbar on the android and only 2 buttons on the toolbar for the iphone.

So the question is...when you build the js file to define the interface, do you build TWO different interface js file each specific to the platform or just 1 js file that would change UI according to platform detection.

---

I think it might be easier to have two set of UI specific to the platform, rather than change style on platform detection, because the UX might even be different, so the code for UX and UI would be rather complex? what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

I think, having two sets of UI specific to the platform is better option.
the example applications (which comes in-built with titanium studio) shows how to decide the platform. Below is the code from the example application:

```
var osname = Ti.Platform.osname,
    version = Ti.Platform.version,
    height = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,
    width = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;

//considering tablet to have one dimension over 900px - this is imperfect, so you should feel free to decide
//yourself what you consider a tablet form factor for android
var isTablet = osname === 'ipad' || (osname === 'android' && (width > 899 || height > 899));

var Window;
if (isTablet) {
        Window = require('ui/tablet/ApplicationWindow');
}
else {
    // Android uses platform-specific properties to create windows.
    // All other platforms follow a similar UI pattern.
    if (osname === 'android') {
        Window = require('ui/handheld/android/ApplicationWindow');
    }
    else {
        Window = require('ui/handheld/ApplicationWindow');
    }
}
new Window().open();
```

Comment: It's better to have an app-level function and an app-level variable to store the platform and version as Ti has to go into the OS each time you call `Ti.Platform.osname`.  Additionally, you don't have to keep putting `osname === 'android'` all the time and use `if (app.isAndroid()) {}` instead.

Comment: @Cyntech, where is this "app" for app.isAndroid defined?

Comment: @TonyAdams I use a global app variable (defined in my bootsrap js file) to store top level configuration variables or functions, even windows. However, I've not coded Ti since Alloy has come along, so the  accepted method for doing this sort of thing may have changed.

Comment: @TonyAdams, you can use Ti.App.variableName for making global variables. So for example, in above case: Ti.App.isTablet = (osname === 'ipad' || (osname === 'android' && (width > 899 || height > 899))) ;

Comment: @DhairyaVora, Cyntech, thanks! that is very good stuff to know!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to separate your business logic & UI `.js` files. Also create one `.js` file for each platform and you can specify the correct js URL depending on the platform. You can refer to the Kitchen Sink example of tabs for a clear idea.